# Elasticsearch score exact matches equally regardless of field length

Tags: elasticsearch, search

I have a simple index with one field which is an array of specialties. One record is

*"specialties" : ["hand"]*

and the other record is

*"specialties" : ["hand","foot","eye"]*

when i do the following query

```
GET test/_search/
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "specialties": {
        "value": "hand",
        "boost": 1.0
      }
    }
  }
}
```

i get

```
"hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "test",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "XRrLTHUBX_caCRKF8MQI",
        "_score" : 0.22920427,
        "_source" : {
          "specialties" : [
            "hand"
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "test",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "XBrLTHUBX_caCRKFAsSM",
        "_score" : 0.1513613,
        "_source" : {
          "specialties" : [
            "hand",
            "foot",
            "eye"
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
```

My question is: **what can I do to get both of these records scored the same when performing a query for "hand"?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The score matches are not equal due to [field normalization](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/norms.html) and to
> resolve your issue, you have to disable the norms on the field

**Using the [explain API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-explain.html), you will find that the score is not the same, for the match because of the `dl` parameter i.e the length of the field.**

The `dl` parameter value is `3.0` for `"specialties" : ["hand","foot","eye"]` and for `"specialties" : ["hand"]` it is `1.0`. Therefore, the `tf` score decreases for the second document (as `dl` is present in the denomiator of formula).

Due to which the final score (which is calculated by `boost * idf * tf`), also decreases for the second document.

```
{
"description": "tf, computed as freq / (freq + k1 * (1 - b + b * dl / avgdl)) from:",
                  "details": [
                    {
                      "value": 1.0,
                      "description": "freq, occurrences of term within document",
                      "details": []
                    },
                    {
                      "value": 1.2,
                      "description": "k1, term saturation parameter",
                      "details": []
                    },
                    {
                      "value": 0.75,
                      "description": "b, length normalization parameter",
                      "details": []
                    },
                    {
                      "value": 3.0,
                      "description": "dl, length of field",
                      "details": []
                    },
                    {
                      "value": 2.0,
                      "description": "avgdl, average length of field",
                      "details": []
                    }
                  ]
                }
```

**If you want elasticsearch to score exact matches equally regardless of field length, then you need to disable norms on `specialities` field.**

Adding a working example with index mapping, index data (used same as that given in question) search query, and search result

**Index Mapping:**

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "specialties": {
        "type": "text",
        "norms": false
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "specialties": {
        "value": "hand",
        "boost": 1.0
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "64471434",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 0.22920428,
        "_source": {
          "specialties": [
            "hand",
            "foot",
            "eye"
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "64471434",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 0.22920428,
        "_source": {
          "specialties": [
            "hand"
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
```

**Update 1:**

If the use case is just to match the result based on the condition (and scoring is not important), then you can go with a constant score query or use bool filter

```
{
  "query": {
    "constant_score": {
      "filter": {
        "term": { "specialties": "hand" }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223488/discussion-on-answer-by-bhavya-elasticsearch-score-exact-matches-equally-regardl).